# Need Help With First Order Intuitionistic Tableaux

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, intuitionistic-logic

I have a question about semantic tableaux for Intuitionistic FOL. I’ll post a sample tableaux that I’m pretty sure I’m doing wrong, and then I’ll post a sequent calculus approach to show where I get stuck.

Here’s the tableaux:

1. $\forall x (Fx \lor Gx),0+$
2. $\forall x Fx \lor \exists x Gx,0-$
3. $\forall x Fx,0-$ (line 2)
4. $\exists x Gx,0-$ (line 2; line 2 discharged)

   $0R1$
5. $Fa,1-$ (line 3; line 3 discharged)
6. $Ga,0-$ (line 4)
7. $Fa \lor Ga,0+$ (line 1)

   8. $Fa,0+$ (line 7)
   9. $Fa,1+$ (line 8)

      $\bot$
   10. $Ga, 0+$ (line 7)

       $\bot$

   $\bot$

Here’s the sequent calculus:

$\dfrac{Fx,\forall x (Fx \lor Gx) \vdash \exists x Gx |Gx, \forall x (Fx \lor Gx) \vdash Gx}{\dfrac{Fx,\forall x (Fx \lor Gx) \vdash \exists x Gx      |Gx, \forall x (Fx \lor Gx) \vdash \exists x Gx}{\dfrac{Fx \lor Gx, \forall x (Fx \lor Gx) \vdash \exists x Gx}{\dfrac{Fx \lor Gx, \forall x (Fx \lor Gx) \vdash \forall x Fx \lor \exists x Gx}{\dfrac{\forall x (Fx \lor Gx),\forall x (Fx \lor Gx) \vdash \forall x Fx \lor \exists x Gx}{\dfrac{\forall x (Fx \lor Gx)\vdash \forall x Fx \lor \exists x Gx}{\vdash \forall x (Fx \lor Gx) \to (\forall x Fx \lor \exists x Gx)}}}}}}$

Unless I’m not seeing something obvious, I don’t know how to prove this with sequent calculus. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Are you just trying to find a mistake in the tableau proof above? Are you unsure about how intuitionistic tableaux work in general, and what conditions you need? Are you unsure whether $(\forall x. Fx \vee Gx) \rightarrow (\forall x. Fx) \vee \exists x. Gx)$ is an intuitionistic tautology or not, and looking for any proof or countermodel?

Comment: I’ve never seen the rules for First Order Intuitionistic Tableaux, so I reverse-engineered it from the semantics. I think I did an unnecessary step by going to a new “world” in step 5, but otherwise I don’t see what I did wrong.

Comment: FYI, $(\forall x(Fx \lor Gx)) \rightarrow (\forall x Fx) \lor (\exists x Gx)$ is *not* an intuitionistic tautology.  One possible Kripke frame countermodel: $\mathbb{P} = \{ 0, 1 \}$ with $0 \le 1$; $K(0) = \{ x \}$, $K(1) = \{ x, y \}$; and $0 \Vdash Fx, 1 \Vdash \lnot Fy, 0 \Vdash \lnot Gx, 1 \Vdash Gy$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thank you for providing the counter-model. I’m still not sure how to fix the tableaux, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @DanielSchepler, plug in  □∀x(□Fx∨□Gx)→(□∀x□Fx∨∃x□Gx) to https://www.umsu.de/trees/ . If I translated everything correctly, then it seems that this should be valid per the Gödel-McKinsey-Tarski translation. I see your counter-model, but am unsure what to make of all this.

Comment: @RW_123: I don't think there's any contradiction here, IIRC while Gödel-McKinsey-Tarski is a sound translation from the intuitionistic predicate calculus to first-order S4, it's very much not faithful. This seems to be confirmed by my copy of Troelstra and Schwichtenberg: Theorem 9.2.8. (Faithfulness) is explicitly restricted to **Ip**, i.e. the propositional fragment; whereas Proposition 9.2.3 (Soundness) is stated for a sequent calculus that has quantifiers.

Comment: @Z.A.K. How is faithfulness defined?

Comment: @RW_123 The statement of Theorem 9.2.8. is that $\mathbf{G3s}$ proves $\Gamma^□ \vdash P^□$ iff $\mathbf{Ip}$ proves $\bigwedge \Gamma \vdash P$. As for `(∀x.Fx∨Gx)→(∀x.Fx)∨(∃x.Gx)` itself, it's definitely not an intuitionistic tautology; apart from @DanielSchepler's Kripke model, a proof-theoretic argument can also be used to show this. Since neither `∀xFx` nor `∃xGx` follow from `∀x.Fx∨Gx` even classically, no intuitionistic proof of the implication can invoke a `∨R1/2` rule. But `(∀x.Fx)∨(∃x.Gx)` is positive, and not a subformula of `∀x.Fx∨Gx` which means no `id` rule can be invoked either.

Comment: @RW_123 The statement of Proposition 9.2.3. (soundness) is that if **G3i** proves $\Gamma \vdash P$ then **G3s** proves $\Gamma^□ \vdash P^□$, where the upper index box indicates the translation that you seem to be using (a different, less familiar translation, denoted by a circle, is given as well).